# Blender boolean subtraction not rendering in Cura 3d

Tags: blender

I am trying to make a simple 3d object to print out on my 3d printer using Blender.

I have succeeded in creating what I want in Blender, which is essentially a platform 100mm x 120mm x 15mm with an inset trough of 10mm depth this leaving a 10mm border around the trough.

Looks spot on in Blender.

I have removed the inset object and checked that it looks ok.

Then I export it to an STL and open it in Cura 3D and I just get a solid platform, it's like it has ignored the boolean subtraction.

What am I doing wrong? Edit : Apply Modifiers is ticked.

Answer (score 0):

In the boolean modifier tab you should be able to see a little down arrow to the left of the "X" button above difference (see first picture). When you click the drop down button, you should see a button that says apply(see second picture. When you hit apply it will apply the modifier and you will see the boolean modifier disappear and be good to remove the other object used in the modifier (pictures 3 & 4)

[Picture of the location of the drop down button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eEHw.png)

[Picture of the drop down menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENGj5.png)

[Modifier Goes away](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BLgs.png)

[Finished product with Difference modifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaiUq.png)

Comment: Yes thank you. All of that has been done. I export to an stl file and then open in a 3D slicer program and the modifier has gone and a solid shape is shown.

Comment: is it possible to get my hands on the blend file?

Comment: yes of course, let me get it up into the cloud. Give me 2 mins.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cDtPgamK_lunIDxWnMBVrIC0x_k7voNf/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I got the blend file and to clarify the middle is supposed to be inset from the rest like a box?

Comment: ah! I got figured it out! so the difference modifier worked but the box that you used to cut out the section was not tall enough so it created a hollow square

Comment: A hollow section within the platform is the desired end result. Like an orthoganal dish. However in Cura3D I don't get the hollow square. Only the solid platform. In the Z-Axis just below ground is a wireframe object that represents my printing bed. This must be deleted before exporting. But the objects base and inset are not subtracting.

Comment: Ok so the model model is supposed to be a hollow prism and in cura its just a solid platform. all I did was remove the face of the underside of the overhang and remake it out of 2 triangles by selecting the edges and then hitting alt-f. I exported it as an stl and chucked it into cura and got the hollow box. [stl file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yj9AZatwV-IkZ_2B4WK0KD95yNaDnbd8/view?usp=sharing) [picture of the result in cura](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vib5HvQ82dUEHeuKDk8FdySZwBYoHjUE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Yes that was it. I made the second cube taller and then it worked. Thank you so much.